# WSO2 IS as KM - key validation service - client permissions

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have a setup of WSO2AM (2.2.0), where WSO2IS-KM is used as a Key Manager and there's an API Gateway in DMZ. The API GW is calling KM on the internal network to validate the access token using WSClient.

The issue I see is that the credentials used to call the key validation service are admin credentials. So effectively in case of the DMZ compromise, the service credentials could be used to invoke any admin service on KM (including manipulating the userstores, I assume).

Is there a specific permission we could assign the gateway client, so the gateway would be able to validate the access tokens, but not invoke other admin services?

Another options is limiting access to KM from DMZ on the HTTP proxy level, exposing only specific URL (service). Is there a list of services specific to a KeyManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following permission is enough to call token validation service

```
/permission/admin/manage/identity/pep
```

You can create role this permision.